# Cannot get python mysql connector to work

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS , python 3.6.9, mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.41

Packages I added:
mysql-connector-python-py3
mysql-connector-python-py3-dbgsym

Execution:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .connection_cext import CMySQLConnection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .abstracts import MySQLConnectionAbstract
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 33
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Could it be that more libraries need to be installed? I should expect this to be handled through package dependencies?

Comment: Is `libmysqlclient-dev` installed ?

Comment: No, it wasn't. I installed it, but to no avail. The behaviour is unchanged.

Comment: Well, I gave up. I removed everything I had added, installed python-mysqldb, and all works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I've just encountered the same issue (on Ubuntu 18.04 too), and trawling through the release notes of MySQL Connector Python I've learned that support for Python 3.6 was removed in Connector Python 8.0.29 in April 2022.
Therefore the fix is to downgrade to 8.0.28, or only install 8.0.28 in the first place and don't upgrade it without also somehow upgrading your python binaries.

to install the slightly older version

```
python3 -m pip install "mysql-connector-python==8.0.28"
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer applies to most production servers of CentOS/Ubuntu LTS that don't upgrade pythons too frequently.